# Error 1062 on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-error-reporting

Today I got this error as icon on my desktop when I turned on my pc:

```
Network Connection

Can not load the Remote Access Connection Manager service

Error 1062:  Service not started.
```

My connection works fine, but I don't understand how to fix this error. Can someone tell me how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is basically a list of services in Windows that should 'start on startup'.. You can try to start this one manually but going...

Right click on 'start menu orb'

Command prompt as administrator

Type services press enter

Find that service 'Remote Access Connection Manager' and start

Let me know how you get on...